# Application using jboss-logging when it should use log4j

Tags: spring, hibernate, log4j, apache-commons-logging, jboss-logging

I'm upgrading a Spring MVC application from Spring 3.1 to 4.3, and Hibernate 3.6 to 5.2. I'll be running this in Wildfly 8. Dependencies are managed by Maven.

Spring uses commons-logging, which looks at the classpath of the application and attempts to choose a suitable logging framework. In my case, it seems to be choosing the wrong one. I have included log4j in my pom.xml, and checking the dependency hierarchy I can see that jboss-logging is not there. Here is the error message I'm getting:

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf
```

So even though I don't have jboss logging in my project, commons-logging is finding it somewhere and attempting to use it, but unsuccessfully. After some searching I found jboss-logging-3.1.4.GA.jar in Wildfly.

The reason for the error is that this is an old version of jboss-logging. I added a newer jar to the server and edited module.xml to point to it, and the error went away. That proves that commons-logging is finding jboss-logging on the server.

The problem is that I don't want jboss-logging, I want log4j. How do I force commons-logging to use log4j and ignore what is on the server?

**Edit:** I followed the link chrisharm put up and added these lines to the standalone.xml file :

```
<add-logging-api-dependencies value="false"/>
<use-deployment-logging-config value="false"/>
```

I also changed the module.xml to point to the older jar again, since I would rather see an error if jboss is used. When I run now I get this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/logging/Logger
```

This may be a step in the right direction, since now Spring doesn't have access to jboss-logging, but it is still trying to use it for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/How+To#HowTo-HowdoIusemyownversionoflog4j%3F

If you need/want to include your version of log4j then you need to do the following two steps.

1. Disable the adding of the logging dependencies to all your deployments with the add-logging-api-dependencies attribute and disable the use-deployment-logging-config attribute OR exclude the logging subsystem in a jboss-deployment-structure.xml.
2. Then need to include a log4j library in your deployment.

This only works for logging in your deployment. Server logs will continue to use the logging subsystem configuration.